# HTML elements doesn't stay inside a well

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap.I've created a row & two columns inside with the size 8 & 4 respectively.In the first column,I've created a well & put some element inside that.But the problem is that some element doesn't stay inside the well & gets out of the well..What's the problem?
My code

```
<!--Page divider starts-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="well" style="background: #fff;">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/1.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" align="left" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="margin-right: 5px;" />
                        <h2>jQuery popups window with demos</h2>
                    </a>
                    <p class="text-justify">
                        jQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demos
                        demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with demosjQuery popup window with.
                    </p>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> August 02,2016
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">Read more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="panel" style="background: orange;">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color: #fff;">Recent Posts</h4>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="images/3.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" align="left" class="img-responsive img-rounded" style="margin-right: 3px;" />
                                <h5 class="list-group-item-heading">Build your own contact form</h5>
                            </a>
                            <p class="list-group-item-text text-justify" style="font-size: 9pt;">
                                Contact forms are so needy in websites now a days.you can say that contact forms are the need of any website.There are many companies..
                            </p>
                        </li>

                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="images/2.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" align="left" class="img-responsive img-rounded" style="margin-right: 3px;" />
                                <h5 class="list-group-item-heading">Build your own contact form</h5>
                            </a>
                            <p class="list-group-item-text text-justify" style="font-size: 9pt;">
                                Contact forms are so needy in websites now a days.you can say that contact forms are the need of any website.There are many companies..
                            </p>
                        </li>

                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="images/1.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" align="left" class="img-responsive img-rounded" style="margin-right: 3px;" />
                                <h5 class="list-group-item-heading">Build your own contact form</h5>
                            </a>
                            <p class="list-group-item-text text-justify" style="font-size: 9pt;">
                                Contact forms are so needy in websites now a days.you can say that contact forms are the need of any website.There are many companies..
                            </p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="images/1.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" align="left" class="img-responsive img-rounded" style="margin-right: 3px;" />
                                <h5 class="list-group-item-heading">Build your own contact form</h5>
                            </a>
                            <p class="list-group-item-text text-justify" style="font-size: 9pt;">
                                Contact forms are so needy in websites now a days.you can say that contact forms are the need of any website.There are many companies..
                            </p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Page divider ends-->
```

> The **Read more** button doesn't stay & gets out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a `<div class="row">` before the date and `</div>` after the button. the section should look like:

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> August 02,2016
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">Read more</a>
</div>
```